# How can I run disqus in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, disqus

I'm trying to add disqus comments per-marker on a google map. To make it per-marker, I've added an iframe to the infowindow, with a different URL for each marker. It works, and I can post comments, but the infowindow isn't updated after a successful post; the spinner remains. Firebug says:

```
Access to 'file:///foo/gmap/comments.html?dsq=12066893#comment-12066893' from script denied
redirect()thread?x...200)&cbp= (line 11)
onload(load )
```

The HTML code looks like this:

My GMapEZ Maps

```
<div class="GMapEZ GSmallMapControl GSmallMapTypeControl"
    style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  <a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=41.092104,-85.144740&amp;spn=0.006130,0.009795&amp;t=k&amp;hl=en">
    A
  </a>
  <div>
    <iframe src='comments.html'>
  </div>
</div>
```

The comments page looks like:

```
<script>
var disqus_developer = "1";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/firehazard/embed.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread the problem is the refreshing of the iframe.
http://groups.google.com/group/disqus-dev/browse_thread/thread/e2213ce3882c855b/ea39c52f354c0572?lnk=gst&q=iframe#ea39c52f354c0572

But Disqus has now a new theme (Narcissus) that resolve this problem, which allows for the client to receive the posted comment without reloading the page. This resolved the problem for me.